# Get specific java version with powershell

Tags: java, powershell

I have some issues with getting the java version out as a string.
In a batch script I have done it like this:

```
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('%EXTRACTPATH%\Java\jdk_extract\bin\java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "JAVAVER=%%j.%%k.%%l_%%m"
```

The output is: 1.8.0_121

Now I want to do this for PowerShell, but my output is:  `1.8.0_12`, I miss one "1" in the end Now I have tried it with trim and split but nothing gives me the right output can someone help me out?
This is what I've got so var with PowerShell

```
$javaVersion = (& $extractPath\Java\jdk_extract\bin\java.exe -fullversion 2>&1)
$javaVersion = "$javaVersion".Trim("java full version """).TrimEnd("-b13")
```

The full output is: java full version "1.8.0_121-b13"

Comment: Please edit the question and add the original version string that is to be parsed.

Comment: @vonPryz done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TrimEnd()` works a little different, than you might expect:

```
'1.8.0_191-b12'.TrimEnd('-b12')
```

results in: `1.8.0_19` and so does:

```
'1.8.0_191-b12'.TrimEnd('1-b2')
```

The reason is, that `TrimEnd()` removes a trailing set of characters, not a substring. So `.TrimEnd('-b12')` means: remove all occurrences of any character of the set '-b12' from the end of the string. And that includes the last `'1'` before the `'-'`.

A better solution in your case would be `-replace`:

```
'java full version "1.8.0_191-b12"' -replace 'java full version "(.+)-b\d+"','$1'
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what the "(.+)-b\d+"','$1' code does? so i can use it in the future?

Comment: It is called a regular expression. For details on this particular pattern, see here: https://regex101.com/r/Z3UZqT/1 .

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression for matching and extracting the version number:

```
$javaVersion = if (& java -fullversion 2>&1) -match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+_\d+') {
    $matches[0]
}
```

or

```
$javaVersion = (& java -fullversion 2>&1 | Select-String '\d+\.\d+\.\d+_\d+').Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this worked to ;) i have used the -replace for now